# NullReferenceException at constructor when resolving dependency with Unity IOC for a Windows Azure cloud service

Tags: azure, unity-container, ioc-container, azureservicebus

I have a Windows Azure cloud service with a web and worker role.  Both roles use a Unity container in the composition root to register types (latest nuget pkgs as of this post).

All this code works great and fine when running in the Azure emulator when debugging, however, when I create a package and deploy the cloud service, I immediately run into this error when the roles run (the web role will hit this when I hit a page that depends on the type in question, while the worker role will immediatelly hit it upon Run).

I am getting a NullReferenceException as follows:

```
[ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "MyApp.Mvc.Controllers.HomeController", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: Calling constructor MyApp.Azure.Messaging.ServiceBusMessagingClient(System.String serviceBusConnectionString).
Exception is: NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Here's the code in the ctor of my type, which is a wrapper client for the Azure Service Bus:

```
public ServiceBusMessagingClient(string serviceBusConnectionString)
    {
        Guard.NotNullOrEmpty(() => serviceBusConnectionString, serviceBusConnectionString);

        _log = LogFactory.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        ConnectionString = serviceBusConnectionString;

        _msgFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString);
        _retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<ServiceBusTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(RetryStrategy.DefaultClientRetryCount);
        _clients = new Dictionary<string, QueueClient>();
    }
```

And here's the code for my bootstrapper that is called in either web app_start or in worker role's OnStart:

```
var sbConn = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(Constants.KeyServiceBusConnectionString);
container.RegisterType<IMessagingClient, ServiceBusMessagingClient>(new InjectionConstructor(sbConn));
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting such exception?  I can't see in the ctor code anything that might yield a null reference.  And I don't understand why it works in the emulator but not in the cloud deployment.  I've already verified the cloud settings to make sure my connection string is there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok...I found some obscure behavior change from DEBUB to RELEASE when creating a System.Reflection.StackFrame.

My `LogFactory.GetCurrentClassLogger()` method performs the following code:

```
StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(1, false);
```

Apparently, when in RELEASE build, this walk up the stack will yield a null for `frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType`.

So the solution was to check for null and use a static string for the logger name, if null.  Learn something everyday.  Hope this helps someone.